# html retern null count-up time

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to create a timer upstart from a specific value

JS code

```
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
            var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
            var totalSeconds = 0;
            setInterval(setTime, 1000);
            function setTime() {
                ++totalSeconds;
                secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
                minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
            }

            function pad(val) {
                var valString = val + "";
                if (valString.length < 2) {
                    return "0" + valString;
                }
                else {
                    return valString;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

HTML Code

```
<asp:Label ID="minutes" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>:<asp:Label ID="seconds" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>
```

Error Console and keep printing every 1 sec

> Uncaught TypeError: secondsLabel is null
> setTime https://localhost:44340/attendance:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the script, looks like it does not find your html elements for some reason. There must be something else going on, because following script runs perfectly in my browser as plain html file:

```
<body>
<asp:Label ID="minutes" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>:<asp:Label ID="seconds" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>
    
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

            var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
            var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
            var totalSeconds = 0;

            setInterval(setTime, 1000);
            function setTime() {
        
                ++totalSeconds;
                secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
                minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
            }

            function pad(val) {
                var valString = val + "";
                if (valString.length < 2) {
                    return "0" + valString;
                }
                else {
                    return valString;
                }
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

Maybe you could try swapping  tags with plain  and see if problem goes away (sorry, i don't know ASP and if it affects  in your example).

Comment: Script can be a bit late to refresh count if it has some other work to do, so if you need it to show precise seconds even after long periond of time passed, you could start by getting timestamp `let startTime = Date.now()` at the start of the script and change `setInterval` callback to display time difference between start and now. 
`function settime() { let totalSeconds = ( Date.now() - startTime)  / 1000; /* rest of the function stays the same */ }`

Comment: oh it is my bad because I am a beginner I but JS before labels I did as u and it is work
one more Q can I stop count and start count depending on states of the button Active or directive?

Comment: now I have another problem when I let him start form 18:54 he keeps add 1 sec till 59 then must add 1 minute to 18 but it doesn't work for me it keeps set 18 then reset minutes

Comment: You can do whatever you want in Javascript :) For example, If you leave your code as is, then insert `<button id="btn">Start / Sttop</button>` in your document body. Then at the start of script you can add `let btnEnabled = true; document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = () => btnEnabled = !btnEnabled;` And in your `setInterval` callback function  `if(btnEnabled) {++totalSeconds};`. But this is not the right place to ask people to code for you. I encourage you to learn basics of Javascript, very good place for that is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript .

Comment: As for counter resetting, this would be due to factors outside of what is given in your post. The script runs normally for me, 20 minutes and counting.